# Do Pokémon evolve in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

My question is basically comparing [the Nintendo versions of Pokemon](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_games) and newly released [Pokemon Go](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-video-games/pokemon-go/).
**Do Pokémon evolve in Pokémon GO?**

If yes is the evolution same as that in previous versions where you had to train your Pokémon to gain experience from battle and then level up? Do Pokemons evolve at different levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do.  Once you catch one, look at their record in your Pokemon list and you'll see a button in the middle labeled "Evolve".  Next to it is the number of the specific candies needed to evolve them.

You get the candies 2 ways:

1. By catching more Pokemon of that same family (such as Rattata and Raticate), this gives 3 candies
2. By "Transfer"'ing duplicate pokemon to Professor Willow (By clicking the "Transfer" button at the far bottom of the same screen).  This gives 1 candy